# Dynamically obtain wresult parameter in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am working in a performance testing project and I need to obtain a parameter called wresult (that is passed encoded to a post) dynamically.

The problem is that I can not find this parameter in another page.

This parameter seems to be for authentication porposes I think.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you're load testing [MS-MWBF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236471.aspx) protected application which is basically Microsoft's SAML protocol version. Here are few resources that might be helpful:

- [Setting up a load-test with JMeter for performing SP initiated SSO's with SAML 2.0](http://www.martijnburgers.net/post/2013/11/12/Setting-up-a-load-test-with-JMeter-for-performing-SP-initiated-SSOs-with-SAML-20.aspx)
- [SSO with SAML login scenario in JMeter](http://www.testingdiaries.com/sso-saml-jmeter-login-scenario/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [XPath language reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)